# Thymeleaf - pass variables to fragments

Tags: thymeleaf

I have following template with fragment where I am passing variable:

```
<div th:fragment="main">
    <span>
        <th:block th:include=" :: inner(${item})" />
    </span>

    <a>
        <th:block th:include=" :: inner(${item})" />
    </a>
</div>

<th:block th:fragment="inner(item)">
    [[${item.name}]]
</th:block>
```

If I try to render it I get an error saying:

```
Property or field 'name' cannot be found on null
```

If I render it like this

```
<div th:fragment="main">
    <span>
        <th:block th:include=" :: inner(${item})" />
        [[${item.name}]]
    </span>

    <a>
        <th:block th:include=" :: inner(${item})" />
    </a>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong when assigning variable to fragment?

Comment: the strange thing is that when I move the fragment 'inner' to another file it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

The reason of error was that the 'inner' fragment was rendered during the render along with main fragment. So along with inclusions if was rendered by itself. And this last render spoiled it.

Possible solutions are to:

1. move inner fragment to another file
2. add `th:if="false"` to 'inner' fragment to avoid self rendering (inclusions will continue to work).